# iPhone - Registered default prefs are not written to plist file

Tags: iphone, default, nsuserdefaults, preferences, synchronize

I have this (much much simplier) code on my app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
    NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultsPrefs" ofType:@"plist"]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];

    NSLog(@"--------------- NSUserDefaults dump : %@", [prefs dictionaryRepresentation]);
    BOOL a = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

But nothing is written... I mean, **no pref file is written**. If I force `[prefs  setValue:someValue forKey:@"someKey"];`, then the file is created with only this key/value

Why ?
How may I set all default preferences then write them to disk ?

BOOL a is YES.
NSLog return the whole DefaultPrefs file content, plus some system values like :

```
AppleICUForce24HourTime = 1; 
AppleKeyboardsExpanded = 1;
```

Comment: Try actually hitting the home button on the simulator and waiting a sec, instead of hitting the stop button in Xcode.  Otherwise the system won't save the pref file.

Comment: @sudo rm -rf : that does not change anything

Comment: Where are you looking for this preference file?

Comment: @sudo rm -rf : Xcode Organizer -- app selection -- download (I'm testing on the phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How may I set all default preferences then write them to disk ?

why? That nothing is written to disk is the whole point of defaults. They are default values, they are not set by the user, and they can change in a later version of your program.
It's not wanted that they are saved in the preferences file. Once they are saved you can't distinguish between preferences that have been changed by the user and default values, and therefore you can't replace them with newer defaults.

This behaves exactly like it should.

If you want to write to the preferences file use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:foo forKey:bar]`

I guess you can use a for loop to do it if you really want.

```
for (NSString *key in userDefaultsDefaults) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[userDefaultsDefaults objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

But you should reconsider if you really need to save those defaults. I can't think of a valid reason to do this.

Comment: Well. Let's say I work like you says. If I build a 1.0 app with 2 strings in the defaults. And in A 2.0 version, I decide to remove the first old string, and move the second one (changing its key string) with a new third one into an array. How may I deal with this ? That is my final current problem and the reason why I'd like to be able to read all the old prefs, written by a current 1.0 app and read/converted later by a 2.0 app.

Comment: I'll answer the other question in a minute.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the link for convenience : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443252/iphone-upgrading-from-old-app-preferences

Answer (score 0):

Answer irrelevant due to changed question:
<strike>My guess is that the file DefaultPrefs is **not** actually in the application bundle.  Check that the plist is part of your *Target*.  You'll be able to tell if it's actually in the bundle by checking what `pathForResource:ofType:` returns.</strike>

`NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultsPrefs" ofType:@"plist"]]);`

This will either output `(null)` (my guess) or a path.  If it's `(null)`, this is your problem.  Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949368/nsbundle-pathforresource-is-null) for how to add a resource to a target.

Comment: @greg : Yes, it is. No need to log. I use default loaded prefs in the app and they are here as described in the file.

Comment: @greg : NSLog returns /var/mobile/Applications/92B9BABF-CE37-44A9-B09B-516AC70BCF43/MyApp.app/DefaultsPrefs.plist

Comment: @greg :  NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults dump: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]); writes the whole correct content of the plist file in the console, plus many system things liek `AppleICUForce24HourTime = 1;
    AppleKeyboards =     (
        "fr_FR@hw=French;sw=AZERTY",
        "emoji@sw=Emoji"
    );
    AppleKeyboardsExpanded = 1;`. But nothing is written... I mean, not pref file is written. If I force user default ` setValue:someValue forKey:@"someKey"];, then the file is created with only this key/value

Comment: The other defaults are expected (see the docs).  Assuming `self.prefsVersion` is a property list object (`NSString`, `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`), your code seems correct.  `NSLog()` the values from `standardUserDefaults` right after you set them.  Typically you don't need to call `synchronize` but you could check if it returns `NO` as in it couldn't synchronize.

Comment: @greg : synchronize returns YES. self.prefsVersion is a NSString.

Comment: @greg : the code is `NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultsPrefs" ofType:@"plist"]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];NSUserDefaults* prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    NSLog(@"--------------- NSUserDefaults dump : %@", [prefs dictionaryRepresentation]);BOOL a = [prefs synchronize];`

Answer (score 0):

After duplicating your code and adding more debug statements, it looks things seem to be how you want them.  I've created a new View-based project in Xcode 4, added a "DefaultsPrefs.plist" with 5 keys w/`NSString` default values, and my AppDelegate has been changed to look like this:

```
 - (IBAction) savePreferences:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults* prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults: %@", [prefs dictionaryRepresentation]);

    [prefs synchronize];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"UpdatedKey1Val" forKey:@"MyKey1"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"UpdatedKey2Val" forKey:@"MyKey2"];

    NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults: %@", [prefs dictionaryRepresentation]);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSLog(@"MyKey1 before registerDefaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyKey1"]); 
    NSLog(@"MyKey2 before registerDefaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyKey2"]); 

    NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultsPrefs" ofType:@"plist"]];

    NSLog(@"MyKey1 from userDefaultsDefaults: %@", [userDefaultsDefaults objectForKey:@"MyKey1"]); 
    NSLog(@"MyKey2 from userDefaultsDefaults: %@", [userDefaultsDefaults objectForKey:@"MyKey2"]); 

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];

    NSLog(@"MyKey1 after registerDefaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyKey1"]); 
    NSLog(@"MyKey2 after registerDefaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyKey2"]); 

    [self savePreferences:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

With output of (stripping irrelevant pairs from `NSUserDefaults`):

```
MyKey1 before registerDefaults: (null)
MyKey2 before registerDefaults: (null)
MyKey1 from userDefaultsDefaults: InitialMyKey1Val
MyKey2 from userDefaultsDefaults: InitialMyKey2Val
MyKey1 after registerDefaults: InitialMyKey1Val
MyKey2 after registerDefaults: InitialMyKey2Val
NSUserDefaults: {

    MyKey1 = InitialMyKey1Val;
    MyKey2 = InitialMyKey2Val;
    MyKey3 = InitialMyKey3Val;
    MyKey4 = InitialMyKey4Val;
    MyKey5 = InitialMyKey5Val;
}

NSUserDefaults: {

    MyKey1 = UpdatedKey1Val;
    MyKey2 = UpdatedKey2Val;
    MyKey3 = InitialMyKey3Val;
    MyKey4 = InitialMyKey4Val;
    MyKey5 = InitialMyKey5Val;
}
```

If run again, the output starts:

```
MyKey1 before registerDefaults: UpdatedKey1Val
MyKey2 before registerDefaults: UpdatedKey2Val
```

This is as expected.  You must be doing something else incorrectly because this seems correct.

Comment: ok, but did you try to download the prefs written file from the iPhone (organise - click on the app - Download). Is it created and filled with the default values if you remove the setObject statements, or keep them but add one more default key not setted later ? And what happens if you change one prefs value with setObject, kill the app process, then launch it again ? Is the changed value restored ?

Comment: Just try `NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultsPrefs" ofType:@"plist"]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];
    
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`. No pref file is saved. If you change just one value, only this value is saved.

Comment: Yes, I start out with that code in my answer.  I highly suggest you create a new temporary project to convince yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've created the test project. Copy/paste your answer code, commented the 2 setObject lines. And no prefs plist file is created. Uncomment one setObject line, and the plist file is created with just this line. You sure missed something. Did you try to download the project content from your iPhone ? You should see what I say.