# How do I test if BOOL exists in NSUserDefaults user settings?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I set a BOOL value in NSUserDefaults as follows.

```
[userDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"theKeyOfMyBOOL"];
```

Somewhere else in my code, I want to perform some action if the key "theKeyOfMyBOOL" is not set in NSUserDefaults. How do I verify whether this key was set? If I do

```
[userDefaults boolForKey:@"theKeyOfMyBOOL"];
```

then the value returned could be nil, which evaluates to false I believe, or the actual BOOL value of NO, which values to false.

However, I need to differentiate between these two values (as well as YES of course). How do I reliably do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - How to detect if a key exists in NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397364/iphone-how-to-detect-if-a-key-exists-in-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`[userDefaults boolForKey:@"theKeyOfMyBOOL"];` returns a BOOL, so either `YES` or `NO` (not `nil`).

Internally, it is stored as an `NSNumber`. So, if you call

```
[userDefaults objectForKey:@"theKeyOfMyBOOL"];
```

you will be given an `NSNumber`, if you have ever stored anything, or `nil`, if you have not.