# iOS NSUserDefaults check if float key exists

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I want to check if a float stored in `NSUserDefaults` is pre-existing. The **Apple documentation** suggests that it `floatForKey` will `return 0` if the key does not exist.

How do I correctly tell the difference between a stored 0 and a non-existent key?

Comment: Here is one similar post : [CLICK HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397364/iphone-how-to-detect-if-a-key-exists-in-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A reliable way to see if a default has been set is:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"foo"]) { ... }
```

This works regardless of the data type.

Comment: Cheers woz, this is what worked best in the end and solved my immediate issue. Will probably look at implementing Raj's suggestion at some point too.

Answer (score 0):

If the objectForKey is nil, no object exists, so there is no item stored in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to woz and Bernd Rabe. My solution is this:

```
    //Set volume
    id savedVolume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"GameVolume"];
    if (savedVolume == nil) //Check if volume not already saved (e.g. new install)
    {
        //Set default volume to 1.0
        float defaultVolume = 1.0;
        [[ApplicationController controller].soundManager setGlobalVolume: defaultVolume];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:defaultVolume forKey:@"GameVolume"];
    } else {
        float savedVolume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"GameVolume"];
        [[ApplicationController controller].soundManager setGlobalVolume: savedVolume];
    }
```

Does that look safe enough?

Comment: The way I do it always works, and it's less code. Also, I generally try to avoid using `id` for a variable. If you inadvertently checked a default that was a `BOOL` using your method, you would have a problem.

Comment: Actually, `id` is only for object pointers, so I am surprised that it work for you using `float`, which is a native type. Did you test it?

Comment: Not tested to be honest but yeah - if that did return a float then it couldn't possibly be nil. Will test when I get chance but actually it looks like Raj's solution is the best way forwards.

Comment: I think the point of this is for you to mark the answer that helped you as correct. Not write in the end result that you got from the existing answers.

Comment: Raj's solution is great. One caveat though: You will have to convert your `float` to an `NSNumber` before registering it.